# Golang crypto/rsa problem decrypting text using private key from PEM file

Tags: go, encryption, cryptography, rsa

So i'm building a basic generator/encryptor/decryptor for RSA keys in Golang.

I have four main functions.

**GenKeys()** generates the key pair using rsa.GenerateKey, then writes this private key to a pem file.

**GetKeys()** Gets the private key from the pem file.

**Encrypt()** Encrypts a string manually entered into the console and then spits out the ciphertext

**Decrypt()** Takes in the cipher text and decrypts it, using the GetKeys function to get the private key from the pem file.

The GenKeys function works fine. And the Encrypt function works fine. Entering a string and spitting out a cipher text.

But I get `crypto/rsa: decryption error` when I run the decrypt flag.

**Tried:**

The private key is identical when I gen the key to when i Import it again from the pem file.
Ive tried the different decryption methods included in the crypto package.
I've tried just importing the ciphertext directly from the encrypt method into the decrypt, just in case there was a problem when spitting it out to console.

**To note:**

This worked when I only wrote the private key to memory, instead of spitting it out to a file, which tells me that something is going wrong when importing the key again from the pem file. But I cant figure out what.

Please if somebody could look through my code and tell me if im missing something I'd be eternaly grateful.

**main.go**

```
func main() {

    var action = flag.String("action", "", "Whether to decrypt or encrypt")
    flag.Parse()
    task := *action

    var err error

    if task == "gen" {
        //gen the priv key and write to file
        err = services.GenKeys()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Could not generate keys:", err)
        }
    }
    
    if task == "encrypt" {

        //Get key from file
        privateKey, err := services.GetKeys()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Could not retrieve key file", err)
            return
        }

        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Println("Please enter the text you would like to encrypt: ")
        text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

        cipherText, err := services.Encrypt(&privateKey.PublicKey, text)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Could not encrypt", err)
            return
        }

        fmt.Printf("Encrypted message: %x", cipherText)
    }

    if task == "decrypt" {

        //Get key from file
        privateKey, err := services.GetKeys()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Could not retrieve key file", err)
        }

        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Println("Please enter the cypher text you would like to decrypt: ")
        text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

        decryptedText, err := services.Decrypt(privateKey, []byte(text))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Could not decrypt text", err.Error())
            return
        }

        fmt.Println("decrypted text: ", string(decryptedText))
    }

}
```

**crypto_service.go**

```
func Encrypt(pub *rsa.PublicKey, text string) ([]byte, error) {

    encryptedBytes, err := rsa.EncryptOAEP(
        sha256.New(),
        rand.Reader,
        pub,
        []byte(text),
        nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return encryptedBytes, nil
}

func Decrypt(privKey *rsa.PrivateKey, cipherText []byte) ([]byte, error) {

    decryptedBytes, err := rsa.DecryptOAEP(sha256.New(), nil, privKey, cipherText, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return decryptedBytes, nil
}
```

**gen_keys_service.go**

```
func GenKeys() error {

    privKey, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 2048)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    privFile, err := os.Create("private_key.pem")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    pemData := &pem.Block{
            Type:    "RSA PRIVATE KEY",
            Bytes:   x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(privKey),
    }

    err = pem.Encode(privFile, pemData)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    privFile.Close()

    fmt.Println("Your keys have been written to private_key.pem")

    return nil

}

func GetKeys() (*rsa.PrivateKey, error) {

    file, err := os.Open("private_key.pem")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    defer file.Close()

    //Create a byte slice (pemBytes) the size of the file size
    pemFileInfo, _ := file.Stat()
    var size = pemFileInfo.Size()
    pemBytes := make([]byte, size)

    //Create new reader for the file and read into pemBytes
    buffer := bufio.NewReader(file)
    _, err = buffer.Read(pemBytes)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    //Now decode the byte slice
    data, _ := pem.Decode(pemBytes)
    if data == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("could not read pem file")
    }


    privKeyImport, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(data.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return privKeyImport, nil

}
```

Oh and heres the format of my pem file:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: _This worked when I only wrote the private key to memory, instead of spitting it out to a file, which tells me that something is going wrong when importing the key again from the pem file._ Have you compared the original key and the key loaded after storing?

Comment: @Topaco yes, and they were identical.... much to my dismay

Comment: reader.ReadString returns the input including the trailing newline. You have to strip that newline or use a bufio.Scanner. Duplicate.

Comment: @Peter have tried changing it... new code is `fmt.Scan(&text)` (text being initialised as a string before hand, still doesnt work

Comment: In the encrypt-part the ciphertext is displayed hex encoded. If you enter the ciphertext also hex encoded, the [hex decoding](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/) is missing in the decrypt-part, e.g. `textHexDec, _ := hex.DecodeString(text)`. And as noted in the other comment, you need to get rid of the newline, e.g. with `strings.TrimSuffix()`. Then the decryption works on my machine.

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing a `decryptedText, err := services.Decrypt(privateKey, []byte(text))` which means the ciphertext is either not decoded, or it contains of bytes treated as text. Both options will fail.

Comment: @Topaco That helped a bunch! thank you. So changing my reader to a fmt.Scan and your suggestion fixed the problem. Can you please put it as an answer so I can mark as answered and upvote.

Comment: Sure, I' ve put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the encryption part the ciphertext is displayed hex encoded. If it is entered hex encoded in the decryption part, it must be hex decoded accordingly, which is missing in the posted code. The hex decoding can be done with the [*hex package*](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/).

Also, as mentioned in Peter's comment, the trailing newline must be removed, e.g. with [`strings.TrimSuffix()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimSuffix). Alternatively, [`fmt.Scan()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scan) or [`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) can be used instead of `bufio.Reader`. The last two options do not return the trailing newline.

Possible implementation (for simplicity without exception handling):

```go
...
var text string
fmt.Println("Please enter the ciphertext you would like to decrypt: ")
fmt.Scan(&text)
textHexDec, _ := hex.DecodeString(text) 
decryptedText, _ := Decrypt(privateKey, textHexDec)
fmt.Println("Decrypted text: ", string(decryptedText))
...
```